# Assign <> to empty list in Perl

Tags: perl

How to understand the assign of diamond operator (`<>`) to empty list in Perl like below, does it make any assignment happen since there is no variable involved?

```
print (()=<>)
```

The above prints out nothing but the below prints line count in `<>`. How does the line count pass to `$x`?

```
print $x=()=<>
```

Comment: Side note: the goatse (or Saturn) "operator" `=()=` is documented in [`perldoc perlsecret`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod#Goatse).

Comment: [Mini-Tutorial: Scalar vs List Assignment Operator](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `<>` operator behaves differently depending on the context. In scalar context it gives you the next line read, while in list context it reads until EOF and gives you a list of the lines it has read.

Doing this:

```
()=<>
```

does not assign anything, but it does enforce list context, so that <> delivers a list of all lines read.

Doing this:

```
print $x=()=<>;
```

results in the assignment operator being interpreted in scalar context, so yielding the number of lines (since a list assignment in scalar context returns the number of elements produced by the expression on the right hand side of the assignment).

This also works:

```
print (scalar (()=<>));
```

---

Another interesting aspect is why this:

```
print <>;
```

prints all the lines in the file and yet this:

```
print (()=<>);
```

prints nothing. The reason is that the result of a list assignment expression is the a list of the values assigned. In the latter case, no values are assigned, so the result of the expression (which is then consumed by print) is an empty list.

Try this:

```
print ((undef,undef)=<>);
```

You will find it gives you the first two lines of the input file. Even though those lines are assigned to 'undef', they are still assigned, so they are still part of the result of the expression.

For a more complete explanation of how `=()=` works you might like to read [perlsecret](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod#Goatse) as per the comment by ThisSuitIsBlackNot.

Comment: For "`()=<>` enforce list context", so it doesn't change anything if `<>` is already under list context?  But `print (()=<>)` outputs nothing and `print <>` outputs the lines.

Comment: @Thomson see edit, I have added an explanation for that

Comment: @ikegami thanks for feedback, have amended answer accordingly

Comment: @ikegami ok so now I copied that bit directly from perlop

Comment: The link to perlsecret really helps. But it is still a little hard to understand the the goatse operator. Especially for these these 2 statements: `print scalar(@n=($a,$b)=@{[a,b,c,d]});` outputs 2, but `print scalar($n=($a,$b)=@{[a,b,c,d]});` outputs 4.

Comment: @Thomson ikegami's tutorial on the [list vs. scalar assignment operator](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129) might help. Assignment is right-associative, so `@n=($a,$b)=@{[a,b,c,d]}` is equivalent to `@n=( ($a,$b)=@{[a,b,c,d]} )`. The leftmost assignment is a list assignment in scalar context, while the rightmost assignment is a list assignment in list context. `$n=($a,$b)=@{[a,b,c,d]}` is equivalent to `$n=( ($a,$b)=@{[a,b,c,d]} )`. The leftmost assignment is a scalar assignment in scalar context, while the rightmost assignment is a list assignment in scalar context.

Comment: @Thomson If you are still unclear it might be a good idea to open another question with additional scenarios you want to see explained. This question would become a mess if we keep expanding it's scope.